# Clearing profile data for cached Rose::DB connections in mod_perl

Tags: perl, dbi, mod-perl, rose-db, dbi-profile

I have a mod_perl app that uses Rose::DB (postgresql driver). DB connections are persistent among requests (using DBI->connect_cached) and it is working fine.

I'm collecting DB profile data (and printing it to output in development environment), but I want to clear the profiling data after each request, using this line:

```
# $db is a Rose::DB object
$db->dbh->{Profile}->{Data} = undef;
```

as stated in [DBI::Profile](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI%3a%3aProfile#Report-Format) documentation. But I can still see previous profiling results on new requests.

Environment is Debian Squeeze, Perl 5.10.1, Apache 2.2.16, DBI 1.612 and DBI::Profile 2.014123.

What am I missing here, is there any special thing to notice under mod_perl for DBI::Profile?

Thanks in advance for any advice/hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to clear the profile results by using this line:

```
$db->dbh->{Profile} = 0;
```

However I'm not sure why setting the Data hash ref to undef (as used in the question) or calling the $db->dbh->{Profile}->empty() did not work.